# All VMware (Player) Machines are "corrupt"

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-player

I have been using VMware to run a virtual machine for testing my apps, but suddenly, when I start up my VM Instance, it runs for a short while, then starts showing:

> The operation on file "C:\...-disk1.vmdk" failed.
>
> If the file resides on a remote file system, make sure that the network connection and the server where this disk resides are functioning properly. If the file resides on removable media, reattach the media.
>
> Select Retry to attempt the operation again.
>
> Select Cancel to end this session.
>
> Select Continue to forward the error to the guest operating system.

`Retry` just continues to show the same message, `Continue` allows me to use the VM for a random period of time between as long as it takes me to move the mouse a pixel up to a few minutes, and `Cancel` just closes the Instance, but leaves all the locks in place.

It also shows a brief error message (after clicking `Cancel`):

> VMware Player cannot synchronize with the disk before cancelling
>
> Disk 'C:\...-disk1.vmdk' may be Inconsistent

VMware Player doesn't come with `vmware-vdiskmanager`, but I downloaded a copy from the VMware site, and ran `vmware-vdiskmanager -R C:\\...-disk1.vmdk`, but it simply states `No errors were found on the virtual disk`.

I then ran a secondary, older VM that I had been using before my present one, and after starting that one up, the same errors appeared. Has something gone wrong with VMware Player, or has something tragic happened to my system (possibly the RAM/Disk)?

Comment: Bad "Ram" wouldn't cause this.

Comment: @Ramhound I concur, after discussing it with a colleague who also thinks that RAM is unlikely, possibly a physical disk problem

Comment: Is the disk full? Does other disk operations work as expected on this disk and/or directory? Any security software (such as antivirus) running amok? Are you clean from malware?

Comment: @MattBianco Nope, 30G free on the VM, 200G free on the Host. And I can still access host files ok. In terms of antivirus, I use ESET, but nothing has changed in it, so that shouldn't have changed anything. And as for malware, should be, been running eset av and firewall since I set the system up several months ago

Comment: The host's disks/file system may be corrupt, and when you start a VM it's temporary files hit that 'bad' spot...  Do a full disk check (`chkdsk /r`) on the host to test the file-system.

Comment: @techie007 Would love too, but the system doesn't stay stable for long enough to do that. When the message is shown, it locks the system until a button is clicked, most of which don't change a thing. But that would also be specific to a single machine, rather than both the VMs I have

Comment: I'm confused now... What message are you talking about?  VMs/VMWare aside, if the _Host_ computer isn't stable enough to run a disk check then no wonder you have troubles starting things (like the VMs)??  If you suspect host RAM/disk problems (as you suggest) then check the host's disks and RAM, and perhaps reinstall VMware.

Comment: @techie007 nope, the host computer is fine, but that has not shown any errors. Sorry, was getting confused between `chkdsk`ing the host or vm, my mistake. But I will try re-installing vmware player again, that might fix it

Comment: So you DID do a CHKDSK and it turned up OK?  :)

Comment: @techie007 on the host, yup, its all fine, but still reporting the same errors

Comment: If you create a new VM from scratch, does it work as expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem. About 3 months ago, I compressed my entire hard drive to save space, and it was quite significant. But it had compressed the vm disk files as well, and vmware player had not detected it.

Windows was also saying that I couldn't decompress the file due to a file system limitation, so I used `vdiskmanager -r <...> -t 1 <...>` to convert my disks into smaller ones, I was able to decompress them and my VM's are back up and running.